# Why the flag " is belonging to other site" is Limited?

Tags: discussion

I see a question on this site and tried to flag it as belonging to Server Fault, so when I have tried to do it this choices revealed for me:

[image]

Why server Fault isn't included? and Why we can flag the question to be belonging to other site only for a specific sites of stack Exchange? Or How the site select the returned result for flagging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The practical number of bullets that can go into that dialog is obviously limited, so SE has to pick and choose, based on the following criteria:

1. Which sites are likely to be used most often as migration targets,
2. Which sites are likely to be abused the most as migration targets.

Both criteria are judged by real data: statistics that tell SE how often questions are migrated to a particular target site, and what percentage of those migrations are actually successful.  In addition, the subject matter of both sites is considered; questions asked on Stack Overflow are unlikely to ever be migrated to the Bicycling site, for example.

Sites are sometimes excluded from the list because history has shown that a high percentage of migrations are rejected by the target site, an indication that the folks migrating the questions do not fully understand the target site's scope.

Comment: That makes sense but I just found a question that *really* belongs to a very specific SE site. But as it's not displayed I can't select it. Displaying sites that rank high does not help in such cases so at least a search box for other SE sites should be displayed.

Comment: it does not make any sense. Most of the questions I'd like to vote belong to other sites (especially Raspberry pi or ubuntu) - and as we cant vote for them they will never get enough votes to be on that list. It makes this option almost useless.